# Delphi TWebBrowser Javascript Captcha not working

Tags: javascript, delphi, captcha, twebbrowser

With a TWebBrowser on a form I navigate to a website that presents a captcha. For some reason, the captcha doesn't work when the page is loaded in TWebBrowser. This specific captcha wants the user to drag a slider, but in TWebBrowser the slider isn't dragable. When the page is loaded directly in IE/Firefox/Chrome, the captcha works without problems.

I am aware of the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION issues and set the registry value for the delphi app to 11001 (0x2AF9) to enforce IE11 emulation and any other thinkable value to no avail.

The simple Delphi app is like this.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://bio.visaforchina.org/#/nav/quickSelection?visacenterCode=DUS2&request_locale=de_DE&site_alias=DUS2_DE');
end;

end.
```

To set the IE11 emulation mode, given the Delphi test app is named "Project1", you can use the following registry setting:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"Project1.exe"=dword:00002af9
```

To get to the captcha, please navigate to this URL using the Delphi app or manually in any browser. No worries, the URL is safe. It's the Chinese visa issuing authority.

https://bio.visaforchina.org/#/nav/quickSelection?visacenterCode=DUS2&request_locale=de_DE&site_alias=DUS2_DE

- Then on the bottom left click "New Application Form"
- Scroll all the way down and click "Agree"
- Scroll down and click Radio Button "Start a new application form"
- Scroll down again and click large blue button "Start a new application form"
- On top of the button, a captcha puzzle will appear.
- Try to drag the slider (i.e. the arrow to the left of where it says "drag to complete puzzle"). It won't work when launched with TWebBrowser.

Environment is Win 10 1903, Delphi 2009.

Any help would be very much apreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Internet Explorer is becoming less and less relevant these days. If I were you, I'd consider switching over to Chromium Embedded.

Comment: In an unbelievable coincidence, just this morning I ran into a problem with Google reCaptcha in TWebBrowser (on ebay.co.uk) that never happened before.  Makes me wonder if Google broke something. After check-marking all the squares with clowns, the Google IFrame gave a code I was to copy & paste into the TextArea below, which was in the ebay html page.  A JavaScript callback was supposed to complete the deal, but never fired.

Comment: I also noticed IE support is being dropped on an increasing number of sites. And since the Twebbrowser is in essention IE, we’ll be getting more and more problems the comming years... I hope there will come a substitude for the IE controle for Edge, because alternatives like embedding Chrome is a huge load (100-200 MB) for small applications.

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far. Chromium is a monster, as correctly pointed out by @R.Hoek . I have to stay with IE. So noone with an idea on why the JavaScript event doesn't fire?